# Why I get error when I try to initialize an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to initialize an array with n+1 elements and assign the first element with value, so:

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  double arry(int n,double s0);
  int main()
  {
    arry(10,24.543);
   return 0;
   }

  double arry(int n,double s0){
  double s[n+1]={};
  s[0]=s0;
   for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
    cout<<i<<"="<<s[i]<<endl;
      }
  }
```

It seems to be right, but when I run it, i got an error  message in the line 13 as follows:

> error: variable-sized object 's' may not be initialized

Can anybody fix it?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: `double s[n+1]={};` This is not standard C++, because standard C++ requires the size of arrays be known at compile time. What's wrong with using `vector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 double s[n+1]={};
```

`s[n+1]` is not allowed in C++. You should use a compile time constant. Like, `s[10];` or,

```
#define INDEX 10
double s[INDEX + 1]={};
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void arry(int n,double s0);
int main()
{
    arry(10,24.543);
}

void arry(int n,double s0){
    double *s;
    s = new double[n + 1];
    s[0]=s0;
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
    cout<<i<<"="<<s[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you must use malloc function to dynamically allocation memory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

double arry(int n,double s0);
int main()
{
    arry(10,24.543);
    return 0;
}

double arry(int n,double s0){
    double* s = (double*)malloc( sizeof(double) * (n + 1) ) ;
    s[0]=s0;
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
    cout<<i<<"="<<s[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: As this was tagged C++, `s = new double[n+1] ;` would have been better.

Comment: Since he wants it pre-initialized to zero, `calloc()` or `new double[n+1]()` would have been better